# Pointer math in C vs pointer math in Delphi

Tags: c, pointers, delphi, pointer-arithmetic

I have to rewrite following C code to Delphi:

```
register short* p;
short k;
int i;

k = p[i];
```

The result looks so:

```
{$POINTERMATH ON}
var
  p: ^SmallInt;
  k: SmallInt;
  i: Integer;
begin
  k := p[i];
end;
```

Now I am a bit unsure about pointer math used here.

Does `p[i]` mean that `p` is taken and then advanced for `i` bytes?

Or may be `p` is taken and then advanced for `i` 16-bit words?

Also I'm unsure about Delphi pointer math syntax. Logically `p[i]` in Delphi code should look for me like `p[i]^`, but the last variant produces a compiler error "E2017 Pointer type required".

Is my code conversion attempt correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that I will use `i` instead of `d1str + d1st1` as indices in the answer below because it makes the exposition clearer. Once you understand it in this simpler form, it will be easier to understand the actual code.

> Does `p[i]` mean that `p` is taken and then advanced for `i` bytes?

No. It means, that `p` is treated as a pointer to an array of `short`. And then `p[i]` is the i-th element of that array.

> `p[i]` in Delphi code should look for me like `p[i]^`

No. `p[i]` is an expression of type `short`. That's not a pointer, so you can't apply `^` to it.

> Is my code conversion attempt correct?

Yes.

Comment: To put it another way, `p[i]` is syntactically equivalent to `SmallInt((p+i)^)`, given `POINTERMATH ON`.

Comment: Just being explicit.  You're correct, it isn't needed.  Just thought it would be nice to show that `p[i] == (p+i)^` (ie: that array syntax for pointers is just sugar that has the dereference operation built in)